# chrome extension pass parameter in getURL

Tags: google-chrome-extension

creating new tab and pass the image url which is located in `filesystem:chrome-extension`

I am confused how to passing the image path

Below code is working for me, but I didn't want to show image path in URL

```
chrome.tabs.create({
       url: chrome.extension.getURL('try.html?image='+filename)
    });
```

So what is the appropriate way to pass param in chrome extension html file. So that html file content become dynamic.

Comment: You can use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) or chrome.storage or localStorage.

Comment: @wOxxOm If multiple tabs get open the localStorage value get override ? correct me If I am wrong.